Android Studio says that "Cannot resolve external dependency because no repositories are defined" despite of I have repositories defined
I imported an app from an old version of eclipse, and after fixing all the problems with the build.gradle, I'm trying to run the app but Android Studio says:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskWorkActionParameters_Decorated@ab68ed4 of type LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.TaskWorkActionParameters
      > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration3'.
         > Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.3.2-10880808 because no repositories are defined.
           Required by:
               project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

But of course I have repositories defined.
This is my build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.2'
        fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdk 21
    }

    namespace "com.example.app"
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest .setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
dependencies {
    //implementation 'com.android.tools.build:aapt2:8.3.2-10880808'
}

Now I have 4 repositories, but with the Google one it should work. I tried adding the dependency to the dependencies but the error ends up being the same.
Any idea? Am I missing something? And also I don't know where this dependency is used on.
P.D.: This is my first post, please tell me if my explanation is a bit messy,

in android there are 2 build.gradle files in a project. Make sure you're adding dependencies in the correct file . The one inside the app folder.

@dhirajuchil Thanks for your help, but i only had one because this was a project ported from an eclipse project. Finally I decided to create an empty Android Studio project and move all the old files into it and solve problems manually.
